# I need a system that completely ignores the dedicated GPU

Tags: gpu

I have a Samsung series 7 notebook with a faulty AMD GPU.
Whenever windows 10 switches the graphics from intel to the AMD GPU, some seconds after windows initialization, it freezes.
To use the Notebook I have to enter in safe mode and do a series of configurations to force windows to never, ever, switch to the dedicated GPU. However, even by doing everything that I can to prevent driver instalation (a complete removal of the GPU wont work for some reason, it must stay installed as a generic display driver) windows always find a shady way of forcing the AMD drivers into the system... by obligatory updates or by other inexplicable means.

So, I am going to Linux.
However, during instalation, the moment that Ubuntu recognizes that a dedicated GPU existis, it tries to install the drivers and everything freezes.

Is there a way for me to install a Linux system that will, during instalation and beyond, forever ignore the existence of the dedicated GPU?

Ps. No the BIOS doest not have a option to turn the GPU off or to force only intel graphics.

I will apreciate a lot if you guys can help me. It would save a Notebook.

Comment: To completely ignore you have to compile a custom kernel without the driver.  You can do this on any OS but custom kernels are typically not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the graphic cards using grub.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

There is a line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. Add `radeon.modeset=0` to disable the AMD or  `nomodeset` to disable all  graphic cards
The line shoult look something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splasha radeon.modeset=0"
```

Then run and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Sir, you have just save a notebook. Thank you so much for your solution.